# https to http while keeping path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have here a little problem with a website and its WordPress blog.

For a short time, we had setup everything with https, until we were facing some issues and had to go back to HTTP.

Back then, I had a little collection of `.htaccess` files to deal with these kinds of problems, but I never actually tried my "non-www to www - ssl"

The intent was to **add www and redirect https to http**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Seemed pretty simple to me and I thought it should work.

I have two `.htaccess` files, one for `http://www.example.com/` and one for `http://www.example.com/blog` both with the same content, as users are primarily coming from SE's via Blog.

The Problem is: If I load `https://www.example.com/blog` I get redirected to `http://www.example.com/` instead of `http://www.example.com/blog`.

While writing the Question I thought I try this Question I had the idea to add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but then I get only redirected to `http://www.example.com/{REQUEST_URI}`

Could someone please tell me how I can keep the path on that redirect query?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

If you notice that in your other directive you have `%{REQUEST_URI}`. You are missing the `%` prefix above. This is required syntax in order to get the value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable. But also note that the value of `REQUEST_URI` already includes a slash prefix, so the slash should be omitted from the *substitution*. ie. instead of `/{REQUEST_URI}` it should be `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Also note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (`^/?$`) only matches the root of your site (or `/blog` subdirectory if this `.htaccess` file is in that subdirectory). You need to match *everything*. So, modify the above `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I've also hardcoded the domain, otherwise, you'll end up with a double redirect when requesting the non-canonical (ie. non-www) host.

Comment: THank you very much, I will give it a try as soon as I can!

Comment: I had modified the `.htaccess` file several times. first I had modified the lower part, second I had reverted and edited the upper part. Tried it several times and in the end I realized that I ONLY need the https to http part for the `.htaccess` file and I searched again and found these lines wo be actually working: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` ... Nothing else needed besides of the normal Wordpress lines in the file.

Comment: Presumably you are canonicalising the www/non-www somewhere? It's just that if you don't do that in `.htaccess`, at the time you do the https to http redirect, then you'll end up with a double redirect when requesting the non-canonical hostname. Note also, you don't need to capture the URL-path (ie. `(.*)`) if this is not being used in the _substitution_. This should simply be `.*` or just `^` - in order to match all requests.